# Created file is not visible in the gallery, but is visible in a sdcard folder

Tags: android, gallery, sd-card

I've added a video file in /mnt/sdcard/DCIM/somefolder
But it is not visible in the gallery. 
Could anyone help me please to understand what is wrong?

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "/somefolder");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    mrec.setOutputFile(dir.getPath() + "/video" + ".mp4");
```

Comment: After inserted file call this `context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255010/stored-file-of-bitmap-is-not-displayed-when-querying-for-all-files-in-the-same-f

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just add these lines:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

Comment: You might want to mark the answers that helped you as "Accepted" then, seeing as on your profile you hadn't accepted a single one.

Comment: I remember :) But I could do it in 5 minutes :) Now I've done :)